# accessing image resource in java ( jboss server)

Tags: java, image, jboss, resources

I'm trying access image in java code.
For jboss server getting file not found exception.

```
Image logo = new getImage("/images/test_image.bmp");    

public getImage(String fileName) throws Exception
{

    try{
        image=Image.getInstance(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)),null);
    }catch (Exception e ){
                    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

exception -

```
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /images/test_image.bmp
```

test_image.bmp is stored in src->images folder.

Is there any solution?

Comment: What is the folder name `image` or `images`?

Comment: Look in the war, `/images/test_image.bmp` must be there (case sensitive). Also the resource must be in the same jar/war/ear as the `getClass()`. With inheritance one could use a concrete class: `MyClass.class.getResource...`. Or a `ClassLoader.getR...("images/test_image.bmp")`. And finally try a `.png` as `.bmp` was a later addition.

Comment: after using MyClass.class.getResource.. I'm getting error for document.setWriter() methos..no such method found while creating pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this by using ServletContext as follows
    `ServletContext servletContext = new ServletContext();`
    `String relativePath = "/images/test_image.bmp";`
    `String absoluteDiskPath = servletContext.getRealPath(relativeWebPath);`
    `Image img = Image.getInstance(absoluteDiskPath);`

use `img` object where you want.